# How can I return two values from an AJAX query to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to look up two measured values from a PHP file using ajax.  The PHP file gets the values and stores them as two variables.  This part works fine.

I have no idea how to bring back both variables into the javascript.  This is the javascript that I'm using, and the .js file is in the same directory.

```
    <script src="ajaxgetdata.js"></script>

    <script>
    MakeRequest();
    </script>
```

Here is the relevant part of the ajaxgetdata.js file:

```
function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "getdata.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
```

I don't want a div element to put the values into since I need them to eventually go into separate variables in the javascript, and I need to return two values.  What is the proper way to return two values into variables instead of returning something into a div element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you just want to pass a callback:

```
function makeRequest(callback) {
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    };
}

// ...

makeRequest(function (data) {
    // work with your result!
});
```

As for returning several pieces of information, a common way to go is JSON. Have `getdata.php` output serialized JSON (e.g. using [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) like

```
{"theFirstVariable":"Hello","theSecondVariable":"World!"}
```

and then pick it up with

```
makeRequest(function (data) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

    var firstVariable = parsedData.theFirstVariable,
        secondVariable = parsedData.theSecondVariable;

    // rock'n'roll
    console.log(firstVariable + " " + secondVariable); // "Hello World!"
});
```

And you are right on not storing this in the DOM. It's a terrible workaround, don't misuse the DOM for temporary storage of information.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks.  I hadn't heard of a callback.